# Recursive delete of SQLite items

Tags: java, android, sqlite

SQLite db example:

** I don't create the db, it's Android Bookmarks db, which I access using contentproviders.

** from what I understand after some searches, SQLite doesn't support foreign key constraints but triggers are possible - http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ForeignKeyTriggers

**FOLDER** column -> 0 = not a folder (false), 1 = a folder (true)

**PARENT** column -> holds the **ID** of its folder

```
ID  TITLE     FOLDER   PARENT
1   folder1      1        0
2   item1        0        1
3   item2        0        1
4   folder2      1        1
5   item1        0        4
6   item2        0        4
7   folder3      1        4
8   item1        0        7
9   item2        0        7
```

...and so on

On my Android app, I'm trying to recursively delete items from a SQLite db.
I have the ID of the first folder and I want to loop to find all it's inner items (more folders and items).

For example - I have ID=1, so I can easily delete IDs 2 and 3 by requesting a query of all items their parent is ID=1, get items IDs and then delete.

The problem is I can't figure out how to delete ID=4 and its inner items (item1, item2, and folder3) and then folder3 inner items.

Would love some help with this! been trying for hours :\

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want (have) to solve the problem, in (one) SQL statement or in "Java"?

Comment: @home in Java (I'll alter it later with some Android API I have to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in java then something like this I think, I think functions like `findNextChildId` should not be a problem:

```
 deleteFolderAndSub(int id){
        int childId = findNextChildId(id);
         //Let -1 be that there are no more children
        while (childId!=-1){
        if (checkIfFolder(childId)){
            deleteFolderAndSub(childId);
    //on exiting from above function folder should be empty so it can be deleted without problem
            deleteEmptyFolder(id);
        } else {
            deleteitem(id);
        }
//it should be while loop and we have to find another child inside the loop
        childId = findNextChildId(id)
      }
    }

findNextChildId(int parentId){
   Coursor yourCoursor;
  while(yourCoursor.moveToNext()){
    if (parentId==yourCoursor.getInt("PARENT")){
        yourCoursor.getInt("ID");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Testing your code with some changes. might work. moveToFirst() and moveToNext() will replace the findNextChildId

Comment: yeah, just figured that out while you wrote it :) Great! that should do the trick after some changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to use [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) on your "parent" column. That way when ever a parent is deleted, all the folders and files that specify it as a parent will also be deleted. This results will then "cascade" through you database.

So you'd create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE files (id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, folder INTEGER CHECK(FOLDER EQUALS 0 OR FOLDER = 1), parent REFERENCES id);
```

That's it. Now everytime you delete a parent folder all of it's children will be deleted. You don't have to do anything else.

P.S. Having boolean attributes (like your folder column in this case), is generally considered bad practice. In your case it would be better to have the folders and file in different tables because they're different things. This is called [normilisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation). That said, I could see the argument being made that the way you have things setup now is still ok because technically folders are just files that have a special flag set. You should still probably look into the idea of creating to different tables though.

Comment: sounds like the solution. I really could use an example of how to use this on a query...

Comment: Amazing answer :) the problem is I don't create the table, it's an Android SQLite table (I access it using contentProviders - managedQuery...).
Anyway I can use this when I query the db?

Comment: Oh, the table isn't yours? Hmm....this solution will then not work for you. I'll have to think of something else.